# AngularJS 1.3.8 Using multiple controllers, second controller is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-bootstrap

How do you use multiple controllers for AngularJS 1.3.8?

I've tried the following below but only the first controller outputs correctly and the second controller outputs with `{{ name }}` and `{{ age }}`.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <label>Name:</label>
        <input ng-model="name">
    <label>Age:</label>
        <input ng-model="age">
    <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
    <h1>{{ age * 2 }}</h1>
</div>

<div ng-app="app2" ng-controller="Ctrl2">
    <label>Name:</label>
        <input ng-model="name">
    <label>Age:</label>
        <input ng-model="age">
    <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
    <h1>{{ age }}</h1>
</div>

<script>
    angular.module('app', [])
        .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.name = "Jason";
            $scope.age = "21";
            $scope.$watch('name', function(){ // Logs the amount of times name changes
               console.log($scope.name);
            });
        }]);
</script>

<script>
    angular.module('app2', [])
        .controller('Ctrl2', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.name = "John";
            $scope.age = "22";
        }]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have more than 1 `ng-app` directive in the same document. You would need to [manually bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) the other. Other wise only the first instance of `ng-app` will be bootstrapped automatically by angular.

Other issue is that there is no provider called `$scope2`, you need to inject `$scope`.

Example:-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input ng-model="name">
  <label>Age:</label>
  <input ng-model="age">
  <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
  <h1>{{ age * 2 }}</h1>
</div>

<div id="app2" ng-controller="Ctrl2">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input ng-model="name">
  <label>Age:</label>
  <input ng-model="age">
  <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
  <h1>{{ age }}</h1>
</div>

<script>
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.name = "Jason";
        $scope.age = "21";
        $scope.$watch('name', function() { // Logs the amount of times name changes
          console.log($scope.name);
        });
      }
    ]);
</script>

<script>
  angular.module('app2', [])
    .controller('Ctrl2', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.name = "John";
        $scope.age = "22";
      }
    ]);
  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('app2'), ['app2']);
  });
</script>
```

**Demo**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input ng-model="name">
  <label>Age:</label>
  <input ng-model="age">
  <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
  <h1>{{ age * 2 }}</h1>
</div>

<div id="app2" ng-controller="Ctrl2">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input ng-model="name">
  <label>Age:</label>
  <input ng-model="age">
  <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
  <h1>{{ age }}</h1>
</div>

<script>
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.name = "Jason";
        $scope.age = "21";
        $scope.$watch('name', function() { // Logs the amount of times name changes
          console.log($scope.name);
        });
      }
    ]);
</script>

<script>
  angular.module('app2', [])
    .controller('Ctrl2', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.name = "John";
        $scope.age = "22";
      }
    ]);
  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('app2'), ['app2']);
  });
</script>
```

If your intention is to use just one module and bind other controllers to it. Then just have one `ng-app` and register your controller to `app1`.

Create a module:

```
 angular.module('app', []);
```

Register a controller:

```
 angular.module('app').controller('Ctrl1', ctor);
```

**Demo**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input ng-model="name">
    <label>Age:</label>
    <input ng-model="age">
    <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
    <h1>{{ age * 2 }}</h1>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input ng-model="name">
    <label>Age:</label>
    <input ng-model="age">
    <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
    <h1>{{ age }}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.name = "Jason";
        $scope.age = "21";
        $scope.$watch('name', function() { // Logs the amount of times name changes
          console.log($scope.name);
        });
      }
    ]).controller('Ctrl2', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.name = "John";
        $scope.age = "22";
      }
    ]);;
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, $scope2 was a typo trying to figure out how to make it work. How would you register your controller to `app1` while using just one `ng-app`?

Comment: Did you miss my second demo? If you expand it you will be able to see the code

Comment: Thank you, didn't see it a second ago. Thanks for the two different solutions. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just define 2 controllers for 1 app?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" >

<p>Person</p>

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
First name <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last name <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
Birthday <input type="date" ng-model="birthday"><br>
{{firstName+' '+lastName}} was born on {{birthday}}
  
</div>

<div ng-controller="myCtrl2" ng-init="">

<p>The third result is {{ points[2] }}</p>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName= "John";
    $scope.lastName= "Doe";
    $scope.birthday= new Date();
});
app.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope) {
    $scope.points=[1,15,19,2,40];
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```